# Additional window Tk() appears

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

```
def welcoming():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo( "Pomodoro", "Welcome to Pomodoro! Click OK to activate it :)")
print(welcoming)
```

I only need from the program to show me the message dialogue with the options above, but it gives me one more dialogue window behind it named **tk**. I am using a Linux system.

Comment: A messagebox is a separate dialog from the application root window.  If you only want one window, then add the text to a frame in the root window.

Comment: I used the pack method, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not create the root window (instance of `Tk()`) and call `tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(...)`, the root window will be created implicitly.  You can explicitly create the root window and hide it before showing the dialog as below:

```py
import tkinter

def welcoming():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw() # hide the root window
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Pomodoro", "Welcome to Pomodoro! Click OK to activate it :)")
    root.destroy()
```